# Importing or Including Styled Header

Tags: file, import, sass, header, include

I've got another problem now with my blog. I'm trying to import or include the header.scss file that I have into my contact.scss file using: `@import ../header/header`. All my files are in one big folder called src, short for source. Then there's another folder inside src called _component, and that's where the header.scss file is.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please include any error messages and the exact structure of the files in your project?

Comment: Oh, it's okay now. I fixed it already. Thanks for replying anyway!

Comment: Okay. At the moment I'm working on fixing it up more, so I'll do that in a minute or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code from file that was wrong:

Wrong code:

```html
    link(
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text|Great+Vibes"
        rel="stylesheet"
    )
    link(
        href="style.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
    )
```

The solution was to add a forward slash on line 6, like this:

```html
    link(
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text|Great+Vibes"
        rel="stylesheet"
    )
    link(
        href="/style.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
    )
```